# How to add search option for Google Map_v2 for android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

**Hello Everyone,**

I am new in developing android application. My application is based on Google Map and I am facing problem in making a search option.
So far I am successful to download my map on my device and I can see my current location.
Now I need to create a search option for the Google map so that if user type some object or place name then my Google map will show that place with markers.
I have looked through the web but couldn't find the right answer.
Can anyone please give me some **suggestions**, **links** or **tutorial** so that I can add this search option in my Google Map application. 
If anyone can suggest me a full tutorial for making a complete Google Map application for android that would be much appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Geocoder class for getting the list of Addresses with the GPS Location .

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(arg0, 10);
```